# django-angular, display servor-side error

Tags: javascript, python, django, angularjs

I'm using `django-angular` to perform basic CRUD operations on a single page application. I have a bunch of form I need to integrate in that page.

I use the following mixin:

```
from djangular.forms import NgModelFormMixin, NgFormValidationMixin
from djangular.styling.bootstrap3.forms import Bootstrap3FormMixin

class AngularFormMixin(Bootstrap3FormMixin, NgModelFormMixin, NgFormValidationMixin):
    pass
```

with the following form:

```
class MyModelForm(AngularFormMixin, forms.ModelForm):
     scope_prefix = 'dj_my_model'
     form_name = 'my_model_form'

     class Meta:
         model = MyModel
         fields = ('field1', 'field2', )

     def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
         ... some cleaning here
```

all along with the following view:

```
from djangular.views.crud import NgCRUDView

class MyModelCRUDView(NgCRUDView):
    model = MyModel
    fields = ('field1', 'field2', )

    def get_form_class(self):
        return MyModelForm
```

Finally, the html :

```
<form name="{{ form.form_name }}" novalidate>
      {{ form.as_div }}
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="myModelSubmit({{ form.scope_prefix }})" ng-disabled="{{ form.form_name }}.$invalid" value="Submit">
</form>
```

the angular part being: (MyModel coming from a factory)

```
        function myModelSubmit(my_model) {
            var new_model = new MyModel(my_model);
            new_model.$save(function(){
                 $scope.mymodels.push(new_model);
            });
        }
```

But when the post fail, I get a response code 400 for my post and I can't display the error message on the form. How can I bind the response with my django form to display the error message? I read that I could create directives for some fields but it seems insane here, I have a lot of forms with a lot of custom validation.

Comment: please note that the code provided is no longer ok (in the question) with the latest release of django-angular. You should have a look to the dango-angular doc (especially for the mixins).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, not even a comment. But I found my own answer. You need to add an error callback in he save like this one:

```
new_inputfile.$save(
   function(){
     // success callback    
   },
   function(data) {
     djangoForm.setErrors(
        $scope.my_form, data.data.detail);
   }
 );
```

And you need to add djangoForm in your dependencies. This point is not detailled in the docs but mentionned from times to times through examples. Cheers guyz

Comment: please note that the code provided is no longer ok (in the question) with the latest release. You should have a look to the dango-angular doc. (especially for the mixins)